# Salesforce is allowing a resource to be double booked when inserting through apex?

Tags: apex, event

An org has an event from 10:00am to 11:30am, and another event from 11:00am to 12:00pm on the same day. The 11 to 12 event is an occurrence of a recurring series of events.

In my custom interface, if I edit the 11 to 12 event, keep the times the same, and add Conference Room B, the event saves and Conference Room B is added as an event relation. The issue: Conference Room B is an event relation to the 10 to 11:30 event, so there is an obvious double booking, but Salesforce is just allowing this when inserting the resource as an event relation in Apex.

However, if I create a new event for 11 to 12 and add conference room B as an invitee and save, it correctly tells me the event relation couldn't be created because it is already booked. It seems to only be allowing it when updating that occurrences of the recurring series.

I can't really find any documentation on how Salesforce handles the resource booking. Is there anything Salesforce does with resource booking that may be allowing me to insert Conference Room B as an event relation to an occurrence in a recurring series from 11 to 12, when Conference Room B is already an event relation to an event from 10 to 11:30?

P.S. I checked, and the Conference Room B has its sharing set to all users, so its sharing policies shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Do you have a specific Salesforce product installed that is handling the scheduling? Maybe Field Service Lightning or something else? Or is it a custom interface? It is hard to know how to help you without more details about what you are using in your org to schedule these events.

Comment: It is a custom visualforce page and apex controller. They specify the details and invitees on my page, then in my controller I insert the event, then insert the event relations. And Salesforce has always correctly prevented double booking by saying it couldn't create the event resource because it is not available. However, for the above instance, it is creating the event relation even though it is booked for 30 mins of the new event. So it is just involving DML inserts in apex.